# validating login form with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

These gets the username and password inputted by the user and is expected to be sent to the validate.php file to check whether the records is present in the database or not. and receives a response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validatelogin() {
    var user=document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
    var pass=document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
    if(user==null || user=="") {
        alert("Please enter username");
        $('#username').focus();
        return false;
    } else if(pass==null || pass=="") {
        alert("Please enter password");
        $('#password').focus();
        return false;
    } else if(user!==null || user!=="" || pass!==null || pass!=="") {
        // These gets the username and password inputted by the user and is 
        // expected to be sent to the validate.php file to check whether the 
        // records is present in the database or not. and receives a response.
       $.ajax({
            url : "validate.php",
            type : 'POST',
            data :  $('#login').serialize(),
            success : function(msg) {
                $('#login-box').html(msg);
            }
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("form submitted");
    }
}
</script>
```

php file-used in querying the database to check existing records and is expected to trigger true or false response back to the ajax -please how can i do this.then from there the code can now decide whether to log in or not.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("sim_tracker");
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    mysql_query("select * from  tbl_user where 
        username='$username' and password='$password'");
    $row=mysql_affected_rows();
    if($row>0) {
        return false;
        echo"$username,$password";
    }      
?>
```

html

```
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
    <a href="#" class="close">
        <img src="images/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" 
            title="Close Window" alt="Close" />
    </a>
    <form method="post"  id="login" class="signin" 
        action="#" onSubmit="return validatelogin()">
        <fieldset class="textbox">     
            <label class="username">
                <span>Username or email</span>
                <input id="username" name="username" value="" 
                    type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username">
            </label>
            <label class="password">
                <span>Password</span>
                <input id="password" name="password" value="" 
                    type="password" placeholder="Password">
            </label>
            <button class="submit button" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            <p>
                <a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think people are having a hard time finding the question in this. Do you have a question about something in particular?

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 issues in your code:

- mysql_affected_rows() will not refer to a select query, you're looking for mysql_num_rows()
- your echo statement will never be executed because there's a return in front of it, so your script will in both cases (either the login information was correct or not) return absolutely nothing. So here's some better code:

```
    $result = mysql_query("select * from  tbl_user where username='$username' and password='$password'");
    $row_count = mysql_num_rows();
    if ($row_count > 0) {
        // login correct, add some code to actually log the user in (i. e. some session stuff)
        echo "You were logged in!"; // if you want just true or false say echo 1 instead
    }
    else {
        // login incorrect
        echo "Wrong username or password!" // or again echo 0
    }
```